# Can't upload files bigger than 10 Ko in Alfresco

Tags: apache, ssl, alfresco, mod-proxy-ajp

Today, I have seen something very strange on my Alfresco : I can't import in the repository files bigger than 10 Ko.
I must say that I recently installed a SSL certificate so that users could access on Alfresco with HTTPS (Apache module mod_proxy_ajp being activated).
Does the certificate installation have potential impacts on that limitation ? Has anybody been faced to that kind of problem on an Alfresco/Apache/SSL configuration ?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Edit : my virtual host configured for Alfresco is below :

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ServerName xxx
    ErrorLog   ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/alfresco_error.log
    CustomLog  ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/alfresco_access.log combined
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond   %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule   (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =xxx
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName xxx
    ErrorLog   ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/alfresco_error_ssl.log
    CustomLog  ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/alfresco_access_ssl.log combined

# SSL Configuration
    SSLEngine on
    KeepAlive on
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule "^/$""/share"[R=302]
    LimitRequestFieldSize 65536
    ProxyIOBufferSize   65536
    ProxyTimeout 300
    ProxyPass     /solr4 !
    ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8010/
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://127.0.0.1:8010/
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: For me this sounds more like a network issue reaching package sizes. Did you try to upload the files directly to Tocmat? Is there a tunnel (vpn, ssh, ...) involved? Are there networks involved modifying mtu sizes or having limitations on package size? btw what is ko as unit?

Comment: I have not seen the addition of SSL via an AJP proxy cause a change in the size of files that can be uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

For the ajp connector on the tomcat side, what is "maxPostSize" set to?  You may try setting it to "-1" to disable the post sie check.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried but same error at uploadinf files bigger than 10 Ko..

Comment: That's strange - if you go through tomcat direct, can you upload files >10Ko?  There's a 10Ko cut-off for in-memory file operations that would fail if your java.io.tmpdir was set incorrectly (or to a location without write perms).  However, if that was the case, you should've seen that before moving to apache+ajp.